# a JavaScript don't return $(window).innerWidth()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not so familiar with JavaScript and jQuery but I am trying to learn using them by making a test local web page for my self , some days ago I search for making a raining background using js and I found this amazing [demo](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/11/04/rain-water-effect-experiments/).

It looks great and I start to read it's files and codes but I got a problem
it has a `index.js` and an `index.min.js` , the source html is using the `.min` one and its okay but I wanted to make a change to it and in the middle of this code I wanted to change something and use `$(window).innerWidth()` , although that the `jquery.js` is added in my html my `index.min.js` doesn't understand it, even when I say `window.alert($(window).innerWidth());` it doesn't work , however `window.alert("test");` works , my problem is that when at the same position in `index.js` file ( not the .min one ) I add my code `( window.alert($(window).innerWidth());... )` it works , I want to know what is the difference? why my `index.min.js` file seems not to understand jquery.

I tried to understand the differences between the `index.js` and `index.min.js` in this demo and I didn't catch anything , but the `index.js` is starting with `(function e(.....) ....)` but the `index.min.js` is starting with `!function e(..)...` I don't know what are they and I taught maybe this difference is causing problem , but I don't know js a lot so I don't know what to do...

[rain-water-effect-experiments](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/11/04/rain-water-effect-experiments/)

Comment: It is the code which I want to add :
var ratioMainImg = 1366 / 768 ;
$("#container").width($(window).outerWidth());
$("#container").height($("#container").width() / ratioMainImg);
if($("#container").height() <= $(window).outerHeight())
{
    $("#container").height($(window).outerHeight());
    $("#container").width($("#container").height() * ratioMainImg);
}

$("#container").css("left", $(window).outerWidth()*0.5 - $("#container").width()*0.5);
$("#container").css("top", $(window).outerHeight()*0.5 - $("#container").height()*0.5

Comment: So how does that code apply to what you asked? What are the errors in the console? Are you calling the code when the document is ready?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the jQuery documentation for [innerWidth](http://api.jquery.com/innerwidth/):

> This method is not applicable to window and document objects; for these, use .width() instead.

Now that should not cause the alert to not appear. Either code where you have the alert is not being triggered. Or you have an error message in the console saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(…)` or some other error. If `$` is not defined, than either jQuery is not on the page OR it is using an alias such as `jQuery(window).width()`

Comment: thanks , but how can I rewrite this line of code: 
$("#container").width($(window).innerWidth());
sorry for not understanding

Comment: The documentation says to use .width() instead.

Comment: So change it to  `$("#container").width($(window).width());`

Comment: sorry but it doesn't work , even window.alert($(window).width()); doesn't work

Comment: so is there an error message in the JavaScript console? If it is not working, there is probably an error message.

Comment: thaaaaaaaaannnnnnnnnnksss yooouu with using jQuery(window).width it is working , thaaankss actually even jQuery(window).innerWidth is working also